# Facebook Pagination Error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

After successfully receiving the first request for information through the Graph API, I attempt to get the next page through the provided `public GraphRequest getRequestForPagedResults(PagingDirection direction)` method in the `com.facebook.GraphResponse` class.

However, I keep on getting `null` as a result on the line `JSONObject pagingInfo = graphObject.optJSONObject("paging");` despite the returned JSONObject looking like the JSON code below.

```
{
    "id": "10100476747286781",
    "posts": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "123123123"
                ...
            }
        ],
        "paging": {
            "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/10100476747286781/posts?limit=200&since=1448931408&access_token=CAAM6MhXVsZAYBAN0tW33gMbwnWhs9HtZChlqsGwjgoR2IB9kZCej3pLS8dZCIOSsufYlVlHtJdkOZAHpr0bsPtZAmfj6ZAiXQ9zTXTe9lUghAuXnSQhZBM6YQfRPy26UfXbp4IQe9gKhG50qUZCURtOFAral1NqO8aIoAZCpRZBthp435HCo4uiZA7LqOIK7vxyT6MJ7e3nzcHyOhBDSSaqWYm1L9xUGzmml8Gg6TCZAzUupZCZBwZDZD&__paging_token=enc_AdCrwK4mXgYPS2XHW9Vjgb0ydGnENZCVb8cdyRGdPidfcQAc1573AWMVKR0DNZBzQmxg5ndkZAHfZAvWSpK8UFcG2SBZA&__previous=1",
            "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/10100476747286781/posts?limit=200&access_token=CAAM6MhXVsZAYBAN0tW33gMbwnWhs9HtZChlqsGwjgoR2IB9kZCej3pLS8dZCIOSsufYlVlHtJdkOZAHpr0bsPtZAmfj6ZAiXQ9zTXTe9lUghAuXnSQhZBM6YQfRPy26UfXbp4IQe9gKhG50qUZCURtOFAral1NqO8aIoAZCpRZBthp435HCo4uiZA7LqOIK7vxyT6MJ7e3nzcHyOhBDSSaqWYm1L9xUGzmml8Gg6TCZAzUupZCZBwZDZD&until=1334148469&__paging_token=enc_AdBEPCJpDZALodXcvmWUJy4rV4mQlFsHFNI8qNlvvVXGYAcZAkB8ZB1i1LRVKZCJND6j71MrINp1FKUDTTgQPZCTEU2t7"
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't `optJSONObject` search deeper into the JSON tree?

Is there an interface which I can use to directly use the URL provided in the `JSONObject` data?

i.e.

```
"next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/10100476747286781/posts?limit=200&access_token=CAAM6MhXVsZAYBAN0tW33gMbwnWhs9HtZChlqsGwjgoR2IB9kZCej3pLS8dZCIOSsufYlVlHtJdkOZAHpr0bsPtZAmfj6ZAiXQ9zTXTe9lUghAuXnSQhZBM6YQfRPy26UfXbp4IQe9gKhG50qUZCURtOFAral1NqO8aIoAZCpRZBthp435HCo4uiZA7LqOIK7vxyT6MJ7e3nzcHyOhBDSSaqWYm1L9xUGzmml8Gg6TCZAzUupZCZBwZDZD&until=1334148469&__paging_token=enc_AdBEPCJpDZALodXcvmWUJy4rV4mQlFsHFNI8qNlvvVXGYAcZAkB8ZB1i1LRVKZCJND6j71MrINp1FKUDTTgQPZCTEU2t7"
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, from my experience its better to access Facebook using REST API's instead of using their official SDK. It gives me a lot more freedom on how to handle the request-response and skip over any limitations which are part of the SDK.

Additionally, I can use my own networking layer of Volley/OkHttp which makes handling requests and threads much more easier and efficient.